# whats the right version for using either scope_identity() ,@@identity (),last_insert_id() in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

im working on asp.net c# ,i tried all 3 of them but none worked ,
this is the sql error(You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')
this is my query:

```
                String st = ("INSERT INTO `service` VALUES ('','" + noms + "','" + Desc + "','3','" + ad + "','" + vil + "','" + pays + "')"+" SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LastInsertedId` property of `MySqlCommand` like this :

```
// cmd is MySqlCommand objet
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long lastInsertedId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
```

Comment: glad to hear it! Thank you too :)